# Can women be Makai Knights?

Tags: garo

We know that both men (e.g. Mendoza) and women (e.g. Ema) can be Makai Priests. And, of course, men can be Makai Knights (Leon, Alfonso, Germán, ...).

But can women be Makai Knights? In episode 24 of Garo: Honoo no Kokuin,

> Jiruba says that Germán's child with Ximena is going to inherit Zoro. This prompts Leon to ask Jiruba if that means that the child is a boy.

This seems to suggest that women cannot be Makai Knights. Is this in fact the case? Supporting information from the tokusatsu series would be very welcome here.

Comment: Only males can become makai Knights. It's stated in the live action as well.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Garo wikia](http://garo.wikia.com/wiki/Makai_Knight)

> The Order required self-sufficient/independent warriors that's highly adept in martial arts (stronger than their priests and greater combat strength against Horrors), strong mental and emotional discipline (to handle their emotions, manage against potential dark energies, and see through illusions), and mastery over Soul Metal (due to its dangerous nature); creating a full-fledged Makai Knight is a lifetime of training. Because males are physically stronger than females, the order decided to exclude women from ever becoming a knight.

I'm not sure about other armors, but in Golden Knight's case, one day in every month, the knight won't be able to fight as Zaruba is taking the knight's whole day. Also, women has to face menstruation every month, and that [menstruation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_cycle) didn't last just one day and disappear tomorrow. A female Makai Knight would be unavailable for more than one day a month, which is a totally bad idea. Thus, while technically they might be able to become one, it is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

It is implied that there have been and in fact are female makai knights within the Garo many universes, although it is very unlikely that we will ever meet any of them or get any names except perchance possibly maybe in an anime or more likely in a novel where it can be self contained. Sad but true

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. It's interesting to know this. Do we have any references for this implication, like the series name and its timestamp?